# Problem with geting text from <p> with Python, selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i want to get output from google translator - i don't know how to get a text from from p or  span in my case . I already tryed .getText ,.text or .getAttribute("innerhtml").

```
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "Localhost:myport")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=opt)
driver.get("https://translate.google.com/?hl=pl&sl=en&tl=pl&op=translate")

h = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea")
h.click()
h.send_keys("hey")
time.sleep(0.5)
h = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//span[@jsaction='click:qtZ4nf,GFf3ac,tMZCfe; contextmenu:Nqw7Te,QP7LD; 
     mouseout:Nqw7Te; mouseover:qtZ4nf,c2aHje']")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the full xpath after sending the text to translate I suggest using:

```
h = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]').text
```

I have recently tested this and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, u did the whole work for me - u made the whole path. At first, it did not want to work but I added a bigger delay and it worked fine. Can u share how u got the full path so quickly.

Comment: Right click in the item -> Inspect then right click in the element in the console -> Copy -> Full xpath